# Unable to navigate from one screen to another

Tags: react-native

[image]
I am not able to navigate from one screen to another, I don't know why can anyone tell me what is the proper solution of this Error.

```
export default class Pro extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          email: '',
          username: '',
        };
      }
  _onPressButton = () =>{
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Profile');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Block row  style={styles.main}>

         <Block>
         <Image
         source={{ uri: Images.ProfilePicture }}
         style={styles.avatar}
       />
         </Block>
         <Block center>
         <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._onPressButton()} underlayColor="white">
         <Text>User name</Text>
         <Text>Email</Text>
         </TouchableOpacity>
      </Block>
      </Block>
    );
  }
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Add your package.json file to this

Comment: Sorry i dont understand you

Comment: add your package.json file code to you question

Comment: my packages are working fine its only giving error on this page , but on others its working fine

Comment: Have you installed all the navigation dependencies?

Comment: Yes , its only not working in this page only .

Comment: There might be an issue with your ```AppContainer```. Could you share it

Answer (score 0):

Use your button **TouchableOpacity** like this :

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._onPressButton()} underlayColor="white">
 <Text>User name</Text>
 <Text>Email</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: No its also not working ,  it gives the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {this._onPressButton}} underlayColor="white">
 <Text>User name</Text>
 <Text>Email</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
```

You might also try this

Comment: It looks like the cause of this problem is navigation. try console logging this.props and see what you get.

Comment: console logging this.props  i never did that so unable to understand can you explain

Comment: in onpressbutton method, try ; console.log(this.props); and comment the navigation method. run the app and when you click the button check the terminal. if it says undefined  then it means you don't have props at all in the component.

Answer (score 0):

Check the route page, because you may forget to add routes.

```
Profile: { 
    screen: ProfileView,
    navigationOptions: {
      header: null,
    }
}
```

Comment: please don't do timepass here